# Why do my SVG images work locally, but break when I view as "raw" on GitHub

Tags: svg, gatsby

I am new to the SVG format. I am doing a Wes Bos course and wanted to rebrand the website to a Taco Shack rather than a Pizza Place. So I was able to make a new pattern and recolor some stripes, both of which are SVG. When I push the SVGs to GitHub they don't seem to respond the same way as the original images.

Here is my Image directory on GH:
https://github.com/VolksRat71/NatesTacoShack/tree/main/gatsby/src/assets/images

Here is Wes's Image directory:
https://github.com/wesbos/master-gatsby/tree/master/finished-files/gatsby/src/assets/images

Do you have to host these? I have cloned the repo to see if I can open the SVGs locally on a clone, and I can. I am missing something here

Comment: Everything shows up fine for me. This sounds more like a browser/tool issue than a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw URL provided. In your case:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesbos/master-gatsby/master/finished-files/gatsby/src/assets/images/bg.svg
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VolksRat71/NatesTacoShack/main/gatsby/src/assets/images/stripes.svg